# ggplot add color from a hue palette

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying out the ggplot density function and seeking to add a col = group to separate out the continuous variable (income) by a factor/categorical variable (race). I am getting an error message
g

```
gplot(data, aes(x = income, col = race)) + geom_density()

Error: Must request at least one colour from a hue palette.
In addition: Warning message: Removed 5 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_density()`)
```

I converted race to a factor variable, and am wondering why this requires a color?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared via `dput()` to run your code and to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @four77 this is the error you would get if something has gone wrong with your conversion of `race` to a factor, and the variable is now full of `NA` values

Comment: Thank you, i have checked and the NA appears to be the issue with the variable

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(321)

# Create reproducible example data
dat <- data.frame(
  income = round(rnorm(10, 50000, 20000)),
  race = c('race1','race1','race1','race1','race1',
           'race2','race2','race2','race2','race2')
)

# View data
dat
#>    income  race
#> 1   84098 race1
#> 2   35759 race1
#> 3   44440 race1
#> 4   47607 race1
#> 5   47521 race1
#> 6   55364 race2
#> 7   64537 race2
#> 8   54663 race2
#> 9   56782 race2
#> 10  38962 race2

# Density plot with fill
dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = income, group = race, fill = race)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

```r
# Density plot with color
dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = income, group = race, color = race)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Also a helpful resource to a similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26075181/multiple-groups-in-geom-density-plot)